# how to fetch custom slot type values in lambda values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have created custom slot type in Amazon Lex bot. Now I need to add few validations for that slot type. I need to do that in lambda function. I am using NodeJS for Lambda. Is there any way to fetch custom slot type values in lambda function. I referred blueprint function (OrderFlowers, BookAppointment). But there they are not fetching slot types values in lambda.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 1):

Your event coming from Lex into Lambda will look something like the JSON object below.  The example is for a bot called "TimerTest".  The intent that was matched was called "MATCHED_INTENT_NAME".  The slot is called "Name".  If you want to run  validation for the slot called "Name", you can reference the slot value as `event.currentIntent.slots.Name` in Lambda to run your validation code.

```js
{
 "messageVersion": "1.0",
 "invocationSource": "FulfillmentCodeHook",
 "userId": "UNIQUE_USER_ID",
 "sessionAttributes": {},
 "requestAttributes": null,
 "bot": {
  "name": "TimerTest",
  "alias": "$LATEST",
  "version": "$LATEST"
 },
 "outputDialogMode": "Text",
 "currentIntent": {
  "name": "MATCHED_INTENT_NAME",
  "slots": {
   "Name": "test"
  },
  "slotDetails": {
   "Name": {
    "resolutions": [],
    "originalValue": "test"
   }
  },
  "confirmationStatus": "None"
 },
 "inputTranscript": "test"
}
```

Additional information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html

Hope this helps.